# Python Script not responding

Tags: python

(I am a total beginner regarding programming)
 I have written a python GUI to run batch files that can activate different Gamemodes in CSGO on a local Steam server. When I run the script everything works, but after I execute a command, the Programm does not respond anymore.

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess

def startA(): 
       subprocess.call([r'D:\CSGO_server\Arms_race.bat'])
def startCa(): 
       subprocess.call([r'D:\CSGO_server\Casual.bat'])
def startCo(): 
       subprocess.call([r'D:\CSGO_server\Competitive.bat'])
def startDea(): 
       subprocess.call([r'D:\CSGO_server\Deathmatch.bat'])
def startDem(): 
       subprocess.call([r'D:\CSGO_server\Demolition.bat'])
def startQ(): 
       subprocess.call([r'D:\CSGO_server\Quit.bat'])

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Settings")
frame = tk.Canvas(root)
frame.pack()

Armsrace = tk.Button(frame, 
                   text="Arms_race", 
                   fg="red",
                   command=startA)
Armsrace.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

Casual = tk.Button(frame,
                   text="Casual",
                   fg="red",
                   command=startCa)
Casual.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

Competitive = tk.Button(frame, 
                   text="Competitive", 
                   fg="red",
                   command=startCo)
Competitive.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

Deathmatch = tk.Button(frame, 
                   text="Deathmatch", 
                   fg="red",
                   command=startDea)
Deathmatch.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

Demolition = tk.Button(frame, 
                   text="Demolition", 
                   fg="red",
                   command=startDem)                     
Demolition.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

Stop = tk.Button(frame, 
                   text="Stop Server", 
                   fg="red",
                   command=startQ)                     
Stop.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)


root.mainloop()
```

Did I just fotget a loop?(but I have already a loop there, so how would I have to do this then?)
Or is it something completly diffrent?

Thanks in advance
(also sorry for not putting the code as sample code)

Comment: Perhaps your .bat scripts aren't exiting?

Comment: as @glibdud said - `subprocess` may start .bat and never ends - and then mainloop can't work. You may try to start `subprocess` in `thread` or you can try to add `&` in command to run it in background `r'D:\CSGO_server\Quit.bat  &' ` maybe it will works. You can also try to use `&` inside `.bat`. But I'm not sure if `&` works on Windows - I use Linux.

Comment: I now made another batch file, that creates its own subprocess and now it works. I think it had something to do with the Steamcmd command. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

did you check your directory if there exists your files or not?